# What is the algorithm for backward alphabet?

Tags: c, algorithm

I try to write a function in C which will map the alphabet with the reversed order of it. For example, letter 'a' will be replaced by letter 'z' or 'B' by 'Y' (case sensitive). It will not transform the punctuation marks and spaces.

I wrote main parts of code, but I could not find algorithm or formula for backward alphabet.

Edit: Here is my work;

```
void backward_alphabet()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;sentence[i]!='\0';i++) {
        if ((sentence[i]<='z') && (sentence[i]>='a'))
            sentence[i] = 'z' - sentence[i] + 'a';
        else if ((sentence[i]<='Z') && (sentence[i]>='A'))
            sentence[i] = 'Z' - sentence[i] + 'A';
        else continue;
    }    
}
```

Now its work.

Comment: Have you tried coming up with it yourself?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I found a formula but it is not about ascii values of letters. If suppose order from 1 to 26; if current letter is N, its new value is 26-N+1 works.

Comment: Okay, so how do you get from an ASCII value to 1 to 26?

Comment: @immibis I only think what happens if 'a' is 1, and 'z' is 26. this formula works for that and not case sensitive condition. Case sensitivity is not a problem. I can write it with two condition, but I still cannot find how can we transform 'a' which is 65 in ascii table to 'z' which is 90 in ascii table, and with other letters also.

Comment: You either have to rely on an existing character-to-number mapping, or devise an array of characters yourself, each character having its index and use arithmetic operation you want with this index, for substituting characters...

Comment: A 256-char lookup table would work:)

Comment: @finesttea You want to transform 65 to 90, to 90 to 65. Since you can't see how to do it directly, you *could* do it in three steps: transform 65-90 to 1-26, then transform 1-26 to 26-1, then transform 26-1 to 90-65. See if you can figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated the algorithm:

> [M]ap the alphabet with the reversed order of it. For example, letter
>   'a' will be replaced by letter 'z' or 'B' by 'Y' (case sensitive).

The implementation is a substitution, and in general there is no portable way to implement it other than a brute-force substitution.  Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), only the digits `'0'-'9'` are required to have sequential representation in the character set in use:

> **5.2.1 Character sets**
>
> ...
>
> Both the basic source and basic
>   execution character sets shall have the following members: the 26
>   `uppercase letters`of the Latin alphabet ...
>
> ...
>
> ... In both the source
>   and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after
>   `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the
>   value of the previous. ...

Note that no mention is made of how letters must be represented, thus a strictly-conforming C program can make no assumptions regarding character storage, and only a substitution can be done.  This could be implemented with a lookup table or a long `switch` statement.

But, if you know for certain that `'a'-'z'` and `'A'-'Z'` are sequential just like the digits `'0'-'9'` are, this should work (I haven't really tested it...):

```
#include <ctype.h>

char flip( char c )
{
    if ( isupper( c ) )
    {
        c = 'Z' - c + 'A';
    }
    else if ( islower( c ) )
    {
        c = 'z' - c + 'a';
    }

    return( c );
}
```

Comment: ok, I found the problem, now its work

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to think about code points of individual characters for this. Just use a string with the desired alphabet, and index into it.

```
void backwardize(char *s)
{
  const char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const size_t alen = (sizeof alpha) - 1;
  for(; *s != '\0'; ++s)
  {
    const char *apos = strchr(alpha, *s);
    if(apos != NULL)
      *s = alpha[alen - 1 - (apos - alpha)];
  }
}
```

Note that this handles lower-case only, but it should be pretty easy to generalize. Or to make the replacement string an argument so you can call it multiple times. Also note that I didn't test the above, but it should be close to working (worst case).

Comment: Micro-optimization: replace `alen = strlen(alpha);` with `alen = sizeof(alpha)-1;` to turn the variable into a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Lundin I think many compilers do that optimization anyway, but sure why not. :)

Comment: Adding `static` to the definition of `alpha` and `alen` should improve performance as they won't have to be initialized on each call to `backwardize()`, although again that's an optimization that likely happens anyway.